# Prevent redirect-loop in Javascript-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I got one ressource which is available through two urls, for example: mygoodlookingurl.de/nice.jsf and mybadlookingurl.de/bad123454423523413413.jsf

I have to call the bad-looking url for one time and afterwards I want to redirect. Currently I took JQuery's document-ready()-function and call cleanUrl() which redirects via top.location.href = "mygoodlookingurl.de/nice.jsf";

Unfortunately an infinite loop occurs, because after loading the url on onload the function get called again and again. What to do?

Here is the JS-Code (I am using a trick to read the URL with a created anchor-Tag):

```
function cleanUrl(){
    var url = document.url;
    var a = "";
    a = document.createElement( 'a' );
    a.href = url;
    if ( a.pathname == "/xxx/undefined"){
        var cleanedUrl = "https://xxx.xxx.xx/xxx.jsf";
        top.location.href = cleanedUrl;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: currentUrl is not updated after the first redirect and so the infinite loop still occurs.

```
function cleanUrl(){
    var cleanedUrl = "https://xxx.xxx.xx:xxx.jsf";
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    if ( currentUrl != cleanedUrl){
        top.location.href = cleanedUrl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can't you use server-side code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jack, I was able to handle this issue serverside by

```
return mygoaljsffile.jsf?faces-redirect=true;
```

in my Bean-method.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the redirect inside some form of conditional test?

```
var cleanedUrl = "https://xxx.xxx.xx/xxx.jsf";
if(top.location.href !== cleanedUrl){
    top.location.href = cleanedUrl;
}
```

Comment: Problem is: currentUrl is not updated after the first redirect (see updated code in post).